# PowerShell force password change of a single Active Directory user to entire forest ASAP

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm interested in a PowerShell script working example that *ONLY* asks for an Active Directory *UserName* and *Domain* and *new Password* as input parameters:

...and, **forces this change as (fast as possible) to replicate with the entire forest.**

The purpose of this script is to let Exchange, SkypeforBusiness (and other systems) to recognize this password change across the forest; so, these systems don't keep prompting the logged in user for the new password immediately after the password change sent to a single DC *(even, after the user logs off and logs back in again successfully to their workstation using their new password)*.  Maybe, forcing replication to the just the bridgehead servers in the user's site / domain is good enough?

I know how to change a user's password with the below 3 lines in an AD Domain.  However, I'm not sure how to replicate that change across the entire forest ASAP.

```PoSH
$Domain = "DomainName"
$UserID = "BillKP"
$newpwd = "pass123"

$DC = Get-ADDomain $Domain | select -ExpandProperty InfrastructureMaster
Set-ADAccountPassword $UserID -NewPassword $newpwd -Reset -Server $DC
```

I found the below example for ***Sync-ADObject***.  However, I'm not sure how to use it with the above script (presuming my intentions mentioned above).

***PS:*** I don't want to lock up the PowerShell console when forcing replication of this user's new password to the forest.

```
Get-ADDomainController -filter * | ForEach {Sync-ADObject -object "CN=James, OU=BusinessUsers, DC=Test, DC=Local" -source NKAD1 -destination $_.hostname}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might be worth wild to read the section on password change replication and how login passwords are bumped to the PDC emulator here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772726(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_repup_how_huzs
You might also lookup how passwords are managed cross domain as you likely don't mean to trigger replication outside of the user's domain.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It seems like user password changes aren't treated as "ungently replicated" compared to how account lockout is handled.  "The updated password is propagated to other domain controllers by normal replication within a site".  I was just trying to programmatically avoid the inherent latency issue between DCs in the same domain, if it can at all be avoided.

Comment: There is a more valuable point in the post about how authentication is handled. If the password fails on the downstream domain controller the request is passed to the PDC emulator and tried again. Also note that password changes are forwarded to the PDC emulator immediately. Basically I'm trying to save you from implementing a process that is going to cause unneeded replications. I cannot account for the behavior of the other applications so I'm not saying completely that your process is unneeded. Just that from my knowledge of AD I see it as not solving your real problem.

Comment: I really appreciate it Ty.  Hopefully, someone might be able to shed some light as to why these applications don't seem to be communicating with the PDC emulator the way they should; and, a workaround this (after password changes directly to the PDC emulator).

Comment: I'd start here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2762344/outlook-continues-to-prompt-for-credentials-after-your-domain-password

Can you post your Exchange and Outlook versions. Do you have some users with newer versions of Outlook that are not having the issue? If so, I think patching/upgrading is likely the most straightforward resolution.